# Expected value of a random variable multiplied by its absolute value

Tags: probability

I need to calculate $\mathbb{E}[X\left|X\right|]$ where $X\sim\mathcal{N}(0,1)$. My attempt is

\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[X\left|X\right|]&=\mathbb{E}[X^2|X>0]\mathbb{P}(X>0)-\mathbb{E}[X^2|X<0]\mathbb{P}(X<0) \\
& = \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^\infty x^2 \frac 1 {\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-x^2/2} \, dx - \frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^0 x^2 \frac 1 {\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-x^2/2} \, dx \\
& = \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{2} \\
& = 0
\end{align}

Is it correct?

Comment: Yes: the distribution is symmetric and the integrand is odd, so this cancellation works out OK.  A more pedantically correct answer would  also mention why $E[X|X|]<\infty$ before giving you calculation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is correct but you don't have to do any computation . Since $-X$ has  same distribution as $X$ it follows that $f(-X)$ has same distribution as  $f(X)$ for  any continuous (or Borel measurable) function $f$. Hence $-X|-X|$ same distribution as $X|X|$ which implies that the expectation of $X|X|$ is $0$.